# Not sure about what Laravel is doing with interface implementation

Tags: php, laravel, interface, traits

I'm really new to php/Laravel. Here's the setup:

In my project there is a trait called `RoutesNotifications.php`. I assume this is a Laravel trait because it is located under the vendor\laravel folder.

Within this trait there is a function that looks like this:

```
public function notify($instance)
{
    app(Dispatcher::class)->send($this, $instance);
}
```

I've tracked down `Dispatcher` and it is an interface. This is listed in a subdirectory under the vendor\laravel folder too so I assume this is also laravel code.

My problem is I don't know where the code goes after this. `Dispatcher` being an interface is where the `send` signature is defined, but how do I figure out where the code is that is executed when `send($this, $instance)` is runs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`app` is a Service container instance.

The invocation of `app` passing it `Illuminate\Contracts\Notifications\Dispatcher` interface for an argument has the Service container resolve what implementation is bound in the Service container to that interface.

The `Illuminate\Notifications\NotificationServiceProvider::register` is responsible for setting an implementation for the interface.

In the end, `app(Illuminate\Contracts\Notifications\Dispatcher::class)` is resolving to an instance of the `Illuminate\Notifications\ChannelManager`.

https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/v5.8.33/src/Illuminate/Notifications/NotificationServiceProvider.php#L39

Comment: thanks for the answer, explanation and the link to the docs. As promised, marked as accepted answer and upvoted. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`app(Dispatcher::class)` returns an instance of the class registered in the laravel `Service Container`.

This class should *implements* the *Dispatcher interface*, and when some other class need a `Dispatcher` the laravel application returns the implementation currently registered in the `Service Container`.

As example you can open the tinker **REPL**, `php artisan tinker`, and enter this command `app(Illuminate\Contracts\Notifications\Dispatcher::class)` you would see that you have in return an instance of `Illuminate\Notifications\ChannelManager`.

That is when some class needs a `Dispatcher` the laravel `service container` takes care to return the current registered implementation of that `Dispatcher`.

You can read more on the Service Container in the [official documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/container).

Comment: thanks for the answer, upvoted but I marked Oluwafemi's answer as accepted because of it coming in first. Thanks for the answer though!

Comment: Ok no problem he comes first by seconds, good question and not so basic as you think.